# Unity Transferring a Game Object to another scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene

I have a **CharacterSetUp.cs** that creates a character from choices the player has made.

I am making a game and will turn it into a multiplayer game so I would rather not call this script for every scene changed. I cannot turn the player into a prefab because Editior.prefabeCreate cannot be used in a build.

- I would like to call this script once (when player starts game)
- Then When the player changes scenes  I would like to take that (player-Game Object)
- So it can be used and then spawned onto a empty spawn point

*I know how to do the (First Bullet Point)*

*How would I go about transferring a Game Object to another scene? (Second Bullet Point)*

*Once that is done putting it on a spawn point is simple (Third Bullet Point)*

Comment: Create an undestructible script with DontDestroyOnLoad and store your gameObject in a variable in that script.

Comment: @mchts That won't save the player object. You'd have to call DontDestroyOnLoad on the player.

Comment: @Draco18s I have this implemented but how would I move main camera to be on the DontDestroyOnLoad Object for all scenes that I go to?

Comment: How would I access this player in all scenes that I am in so I can code controls and collison etc.. for player in scenes @mchts

Comment: The only thing I can think of is every scene should have an empty game object to hold player but I have no way on how to access it to put player in an empty game object

Comment: Why do you need to move the main camera at all? Why can't each scene have its own main camera? This is starting to sound more and more like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: My dontDestroy object I tried it out but I can access it in other scenes to attach a main camera, etc... this isnt a XY Problem because it relates to my first question Where I want to use an object in another scene so I still have access to it in all scenes @Draco18s

Comment: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56066690/unity-transferring-a-game-object-to-another-scene?noredirect=1#comment98773762_56066690), and two, you cannot--in any way--reference an object in another scene: it does not exist.